# Cannot insert into MongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to MongoDb. I am trying to insert the data in MongoDb using java.  Everything works fine but when i try to use `insert()` function to insert the data error is shown. It says change type of documents to `DBObject[]`.

*Database.java*

```
package database;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
public class Database 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MongoClient mongo= new MongoClient("localhost",80);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("Collection");
        DBCollection group=db.getCollection("Group");
        BasicDBObject documents= new BasicDBObject();
        documents.put("saf", "ad");

        group.insert(documents);//error is shown here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error message that you get. It contains important information about what's wrong.

Comment: it simply says changetype of documents to DBObject[].

Comment: What version of MongoClient are you using? It looks like you are using an old version that did not yet have the `insert` method that takes varargs. Use a newer version of MongoClient.

Comment: I am using mongo-java-driver-2.2.0.jar

Answer (score 3):

BasicDBObject as subsets of DBObject. Also to save the BasicDBObject we have a call as save method

```
group.save(documents);
```

Comment: A cast is not necessary, because `BasicDBObject` is a subtype of `DBObject`.

Comment: My bad I have updated my code also we can save the BasicDBObject. As there is a method for that

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is correct and runs as is.
Just update the mongo-java driver to version 2.13.0 from your existing one.
Download link:

[JavaDriver2.13](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.3/mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar)

or:
[All Mongo Drivers](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)

Comment: It says to change to DBObject[]

Comment: I tried running your code as a junit test and it was fine,just added throws UnknownHostException to the method..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.insert()` on DBCollection.

```
public WriteResult insert(DBObject... arr)
                   throws MongoException
Saves document(s) to the database. if doc doesn't have an _id, one will be added you can get the _id that was added from doc after the insert
Parameters:
arr - array of documents to save
Throws:
MongoException
```

Check [JavaDoc for insert](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#insert(com.mongodb.DBObject...)). This is expecting an array of DBObject.

That's why the error:

> change type of documents to DBObject[]

As @Vivek mentioned, you can use `.save()` method:

```
public final WriteResult save(DBObject jo)
Saves an object to this collection.
Parameters:
jo - the DBObject to save will add _id field to jo if needed
```

Check [Javadoc for save](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#save(com.mongodb.DBObject)).